# how to fix deadlocking

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, deadlock

we have a stored procedure that are inserting/updateing/deleteing and we have a problem where the user some times getting deadlocked and loosing data and that is becuase the stored procedure or table is in use by another user or instance.
[image]

table

```
    CREATE TABLE [file].[ItemResourceFile](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Item_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ResourceFile_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDefault] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ItemResourceFile_IsDefault]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DateTimeCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ItemResourceFile_DateTimeCreated]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()),
    [DateTimeModified] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ItemResourceFile_DateTimeModified]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()),
    [CreatorUser_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastModifierUser_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ItemResourceFile_Status]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [sequenceID] [int] NULL DEFAULT ('NULL'),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemResourceFile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Item_ID] ASC,
    [ResourceFile_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [FILE]
) ON [FILE] TEXTIMAGE_ON [FILE]

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ItemResourceFile_ID]    Script Date: 20-May-16 13:25:56 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ItemResourceFile_ID] ON [file].[ItemResourceFile]
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [FILE]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ItemResourceFile_IsDefault]    Script Date: 20-May-16 13:25:56 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ItemResourceFile_IsDefault] ON [file].[ItemResourceFile]
(
    [Item_ID] ASC,
    [IsDefault] ASC
)
WHERE ([IsDefault]=(1))
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [FILE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [file].[ItemResourceFile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemResourceFile_Item] FOREIGN KEY([Item_ID])
REFERENCES [file].[Item] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [file].[ItemResourceFile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemResourceFile_Item]
GO

ALTER TABLE [file].[ItemResourceFile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemResourceFile_ResourceFile] FOREIGN KEY([ResourceFile_ID])
REFERENCES [file].[ResourceFile] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [file].[ItemResourceFile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemResourceFile_ResourceFile]
GO

ALTER TABLE [file].[ItemResourceFile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemResourceFile_User] FOREIGN KEY([CreatorUser_ID])
REFERENCES [system].[User] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [file].[ItemResourceFile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemResourceFile_User]
GO

ALTER TABLE [file].[ItemResourceFile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemResourceFile_User1] FOREIGN KEY([LastModifierUser_ID])
REFERENCES [system].[User] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [file].[ItemResourceFile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemResourceFile_User1]
GO
```

SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [file].[usp_iudItemResourceFile]
    @p_ItemID INT
    , @p_ID INT = NULL OUTPUT
    , @p_IsDefault BIT = NULL
    , @p_Description NVARCHAR ( MAX ) = NULL

    --, @p_RelPath NVARCHAR ( 2000 ) = NULL
    , @p_Name NVARCHAR ( 250 ) = NULL
    , @p_sequenceNumberID INT = NULL
    , @p_Type TINYINT = NULL
    , @p_Size INT = NULL
    , @p_Status TINYINT = NULL
    , @p_DoerTicket VARCHAR ( 200 ) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @doerUserID INT
            , @doerCompanyID INT
    EXEC system.usp_validateAuthenticationTicket @p_Ticket = @p_DoerTicket
                                                , @p_UserID = @doerUserID OUTPUT
                                                , @p_CompanyID = @doerCompanyID OUTPUT


    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF ( @p_ID < 0 )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'TBD'
    END

    DECLARE @res INT
    EXEC @res = [file].usp_iudResourceFile @p_ID = @p_ID OUTPUT
                                    --, @p_RelPath = @p_RelPath
                                    , @p_Name = @p_Name
                                    , @p_Type = @p_Type
                                    , @p_Size = @p_Size
                                    , @p_Status = @p_Status
                                    , @p_DoerTicket = @p_DoerTicket

    IF ( ( @@ERROR <> 0 ) OR ( @res <> 0 ) )    
    BEGIN
        IF ( @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN 1050
    END

    IF ( ( @p_ID > 0 ) AND ( @p_IsDefault = 1 ) )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [file].ItemResourceFile SET
            IsDefault = 0
        WHERE Item_ID = @p_ItemID

        IF ( @@ERROR <> 0 ) 
        BEGIN
            IF ( @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RETURN 1053
        END
    END

    MERGE INTO [file].ItemResourceFile AS target
    USING ( SELECT @p_ItemID
                    , @p_ID
                    , @p_IsDefault
                    , @p_Description
                    , @p_Status
                    , @p_sequenceNumberID
                    , @doerUserID
                    , @doerCompanyID ) AS source ( ItemID, ResourceFileID, IsDefault, Description, Status, sequenceID, DoerUserID, DoerCompanyID )
        ON ( target.Item_ID = source.ItemID )
            AND ( target.ResourceFile_ID = source.ResourceFileID )
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET 
                target.Description = NULLIF ( ISNULL ( source.Description, target.Description ), N'' )
                , target.IsDefault = ISNULL ( source.IsDefault, target.IsDefault )
                , target.Status = ISNULL ( source.Status, target.Status )
                , target.sequenceID = source.sequenceID
                , target.LastModifierUser_ID = source.DoerUserID
                , target.DateTimeModified = GETUTCDATE ( )
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND source.ResourceFileID > 0 THEN
            INSERT ( Item_ID
                    , ResourceFile_ID
                    , Description
                    , IsDefault
                    , Status
                    , sequenceID
                    , CreatorUser_ID
                    , LastModifierUser_ID )
                VALUES ( source.ItemID
                        , source.ResourceFileID
                        , NULLIF ( source.Description, N'' )
                        , ISNULL ( source.IsDefault, 0 )
                        , ISNULL ( source.Status, 0 ) --0: Active
                        , source.sequenceID
                        , source.DoerUserID
                        , source.DoerUserID
                        )
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
                AND target.Item_ID = @p_ItemID
                AND target.ResourceFile_ID = ABS ( @p_ID ) THEN
            DELETE;

    IF ( @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 )
    BEGIN
        IF ( @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ( 'DBException_ItemNotFound', 16, 1 )
        RETURN 1060
    END

    --IF ( @p_ID IS NULL )
    --  SET @p_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY ( )

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    RETURN 0
END
```

how do i fix it

Comment: Don't merge.  it does full table scans on both the source and target tables.  This is likely the source of your dead lock since the entire table scan is encapsulated in a transaction.

Comment: I also see your calling other SPs within this proc - and those are also incapsulated inside the transaction.  I'm willing to bet those procs also create their own transactions when executing.  There could be very large and complicated lock chains because of this design pattern.

Comment: @EastOfJupiter - I don't know where you get the "it does full table scans" from - I can easily construct an example `MERGE` script where it's only using index seeks.

Comment: Paragraph 4 under "Arguments" section:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx